# Highlight weekend with a plot band or a zone

Tags: highcharts

I would like highlight the weekend in a timeseries chart. Until now and reading the documentation I think it is two ways of achieving this: plot bands or zones. I just managed to highlight the saturdays and sunday on the x axis(see code below). I would like to plot a band instead.(see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnoAQ.png)).

```
xAxis: {
   type: 'datetime',
      crosshair: {
         width: 2,
         color: '#F66',
         dashStyle: 'shortdot'
      },
      labels: {
         formatter: function () {
            var day = Highcharts.dateFormat('%a', this.value);
            if (day == "Sat" || day == "Sun") {
               return `<b>${Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %e %b', this.value)}</b>`;
            } else {
               return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %e %b', this.value);
            }  
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my idea how to add `plotBands` dynamically based on the used data. I think that everything is clear in the code - if not, feel free to ask.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6n4ab7jm/

```
events: {
  load() {
    let chart = this,
      plotBandAr = [],
      plotBand = {
        color: '#FCFFC5',
      };


    chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
      // start from the saturday
      if (new Date(p.x).getDay() === 6) {
        plotBand.from = p.x
      }
      // end on the sunday
      if (new Date(p.x).getDay() === 0) {
        plotBand.to = p.x
      }
      // add plotBand on monday and reset the plotBand object
      if (new Date(p.x).getDay() === 1) {
        plotBandAr.push(plotBand)
        plotBand = {
          color: '#FCFFC5',
        };
      }
    });

    chart.xAxis[0].update({
      plotBands: plotBandAr
    })
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything is clear and works really well! Kudos for the quick response!